# Bring up the subject 'to' him or 'with' him?

Tags: prepositions

For example:

1. Let me bring up the subject to him.
2. Let me bring up the subject with him.

Which one of the two is correct?

Comment: To *bring **up** X **to** Y* is only likely as a ***literal*** usage, where ***X*** is a physical object (by strong implication, that's currently "at a lower elevation" than Y, which isn't necessarily a person). Thus *Bring up your homework to the front of the class* (where as in most such contexts, ***up*** is an "optional extra" that wouldn't usually be included). Your metaphoric usage is only valid when *bringing up a subject **with** Y*, where ***Y*** must be a person, committee, or other "sentient" referent.

Comment: They are both correct but you need to show you made an effort or this will be closed.

Comment: The "to" version sounds as if the person to be approached is distant and elevated, while "with" sounds as if the person is more on the same level.